# Local variable used in jsonBuilder with Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

I would like to use a local variable previously defined in jsonBuilder. Here is my code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

variable="""cols{id'Nom' label'LabelNom' pattern'' type'string'}{id'Test' label'Nom' pattern'' type'number'}"""

def json = new JsonBuilder(variable)
```

But it doesn't work! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you want your json structure to look like, but from your description I'm guessing you're looking for [JsonSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) instead. Have a look at this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def variable= '{"cols": [{"id": "Nom", "label": "Nom", "pattern": "", "type": "string"},{"id": "Test", "label": "Nom", "pattern": "", "type": "number"}]}'

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(variable)
```

Could this be what you're after?

Peace!